# Find content with missing entity reference

Tags: views, 9

I have nodes that have embedded Media (images) and also links to other content (nodes and media).  Through hooks I populate custom fields to store those references, this is a multi-value entity reference.  Also, since the entity reference is an int, the default filter is equals, between, less or greater, etc - 'not in' is not even possible via the UI.

What I would like to do is create a View that would find content where those references are no longer valid; ie. the referenced entity has been removed.

I attempted to use a few hook_views_XXX functions to alter the query or filter the results after execution.  Altering the query makes the most sense, but am not sure how to add an IN clause for a custom field.  Filtering the results 'post_execute' will be cumbersome since there is not a way good way to get all results before the pager is initialized.

Creating a custom views filter is going to be the next attempt, but would think/hope that there is a simpler way.  Is there something I am overlooking?  How can the 'query_alter' be done?

Comment: Why do you need to alter the query? Why won't a filter work?

Comment: If a filter can be done that is great, but I can not figure out how to do a 'NOT IN' with a multi value entity reference field.

Comment: You should add the 'multi value' part to the original post, as it's a fairly important bit of context.